# CREATE FUNCTION in memory using ENGINE=MEMORY - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I want to create a in-memory function just as we have for creating a table :

```
CREATE TABLE temp_table 
ENGINE=MEMORY
SELECT * FROM table_name
```

Something like :

```
CREATE FUNCTION temp_function (s CHAR(20)) ENGINE=MEMORY 
RETURNS CHAR(50) RETURN CONCAT('Hello, ',s,'!');
```

But I guess this is not allowed in SQL queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ENGINE =` refers to the storage engine, which is used for actually storing data in tables.

This is not an appropriate option for `CREATE FUNCTION`.

Comment: Answers my question... thnx @Gordon Linoff